# How to call a function just after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback

As `setState` is async method in react. Is there any alternate to work with callback.

**Note1 :** I can use `useEffect` as it cause to unlimited function call.

**Note2 :** Also I can't use `function2` without reference as it's being used in many places.

```
const [state,setState] = useState([]);


const data = []; // data of 1000 
const function1 = (name) => {
    const tempState = data.filter(ele => ele.name == name);
    setState(tempState);
    function2(tempState[0])
 }

const function2 = (element) => {
    const tempState = state.filter(ele => ele.id == element.id);
    setState(tempState);
}
```

Above code always returns `[]` . possible reason I can find is `function2` has called before `setState`. That is filtering empty array that's why I'm getting mpty array.

As mention in code if I use `useEffect` then to call `function2(state[0])`. But inside `function2` we have `setState` method call which makes re-render again & again.

is there any possibility where I can use callback method like this

```
setState(tempState,() => function2(state[0]) );
```

Comment: Don't reference the state in the other function, pass the other function the new state value instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Is it possible without creating new state. as If I use another state U have to manage both states.

Comment: Yes - like I just said, just pass the new state to the function - no need to create anything new

Comment: you mean like this

const function2 = () => {
    const tempState = state.filter(ele => ele.id == state[0].id);
    setState(tempState);
}